# Scrollview and touch listener

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, textview, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I am facing a problem.

I have a `ScrollView` in my application and I have to drag and drop a `TextView` with the help of a touch listener.

The problem is when I drag a `TextView` using the `onTouchListener()`, the `ScrollView` activates and is creating a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [open source project on github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist) released by the CommonsGuy. It's based on the drag-and-drop used by the music app. There is also another drag and drop example [here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. The examples that you have suggested has a list view. Its working with list view pretty much. But I am looking for an example without list view.

Comment: Can you suggest me any such example without listview

Comment: Have a look at [this one](http://myandroidwidgets.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/DragDrop/). Also, it might help if you try do upload an image of what you are looking to achieve. It is a bit unclear from your questions "what you have and where you want to get to".

Comment: I'll try and explain what I want. I have divided the screen into two halves. Right panel and the left panel. Now I have the scrollview set for the left panel and there is a textview in this scrollview. Now I want to drag the textview from the left panel to the right panel.        So, hence when I drag the textview, the scrollview motion event gets called. which is something I dont want. The motion events are conflicting.